# php redirect doesn't work with hiding .php extension via htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a `.htaccess` file to hide `.php` extensions. When I enter the url (localhost, apache) it does work (in the browser I type: localhost/project_test) and then it gives me localhost/project_test/login (which was login.php), but when I want to login (and redirect to another page called portal.php in the same directory) the redirect to portal.php doesn't work

My `.htaccess` code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://localhost/project_test/production/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove the .php extension from a PHP file for example yoursite.com/wallpaper.php to yoursite.com/wallpaper you have to add the following code inside the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I got this working now. Had to put a `.htaccess` in every subdirectory. Not the most ideal solution, but working for now.

Comment: Good Mr. @dexter